# Passing an Array of Values, using Typescript/Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Good afternoon,
I'm a junior dev who's been trying to learn Sequelize with Typescript but am having difficulties.
I've created a simple query to search based off a value, but am unable to pass an array of values without breaking the query.

```
const findNameTsxData = (limit: number, Name: string): Promise<FinanceStuffs[]> => {
// const { in: opIn, or } = Sequelize.Op;
  return db.FinanceStuffs.findAll({
    where: { Name },
    limit
  });
};
```

Right now, if i pass a query on postman as

```
Name: "Joe"
Limit: 10,
```

It returns me 10 transactions by Joe, but i'd like to be able to pass multiple names in the 
query such as:

```
Name: ["Joe", "Alex", "Jacob"]
Limit: 30
```

I believe the answer would be mapping the array somehow, or using Sequelize.Op but i seem to be getting multiple typescript errors when tried.

If you could explain to me what i'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated as a learning experience.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `or` keyword from sequelize like mention [in the documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#where)

Example:

```
const findNameTsxData = (limit: number, Names: string[]): Promise<FinanceStuffs[]> => {
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
  return db.FinanceStuffs.findAll({
    where: { Name: { [Op.or]: Names } },
    limit
  });
};
```

You can also use the `in` if you prefer

```
const findNameTsxData = (limit: number, Names: string[]): Promise<FinanceStuffs[]> => {
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
  return db.FinanceStuffs.findAll({
    where: { Name: { [Op.in]: Names } },
    limit
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you!

I had to modify the [Op.or]: Names to be inside of its own object, but it worked great!